# JPA - Hibernate - OneToOne

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a OneToOne relation between tables User and Profile defined like so:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
    }
)
public class User implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUser;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)  
    @JoinColumn(name="id_profile", referencedColumnName="idProfile")
    private Profile profile;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles = new LinkedHashSet<Role>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="profile",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "discordId")
)
public class Profile implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idProfile;
    private Date birthday;
    private String discordId;
    private String description; 
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> spokenLanguages = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ProfileGame> profileGames = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;
    
}
```

Then I run a test to make some fixtures in my database:

```
Profile profile = this.profileRepository.save(Profile.builder()
                    .birthday(new Date())
                    .discordId("discord-" + i)
                    .description("Description de user-" + i)
                    .spokenLanguages(spokenLanguages)
                    .timeSlot(timeSlot)
                    .build());
            user.setProfile(profile);
            System.err.println(user);
```

Everything works fine here, System.err.println(user) returns correct values.

The issue comes from the database, which doesn't "apply" the id_profile in my User table:

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: The entities are same table or different table?

Comment: Different tables

Comment: Then, why `id_profile` field is in user table, there must be `user_id` FK field in profile, no?

Comment: I don't know how to do that... I'm newbie with Spring ! :-/

Comment: I recommend you read about `OneToOne` mapping a little, checkout this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i managed to get the id_user in my profile table !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```java
Profile profile = Profile.builder()
   .birthday(new Date())
   .discordId("discord-" + i)
   .description("Description de user-" + i)
   .spokenLanguages(spokenLanguages)
   .timeSlot(timeSlot)
   .user(user)
   .build();
user.setProfile(profile);
profile = this.profileRepository.save(profile);
```

You use a bidirectional `@OneToOne` association, so you should make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

Also, as you need to propagate persistent state to the user, you should add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the `Profile.user` like below:

```
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable {
    
    // ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
    
}
```

Comment: It didn't change anything actually.

Answer (score 0):

Class User:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)   
private Profile profile;
```

Class Profile:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_user")
private User user;
```